# neo4j. Matching nodes, but I need to return edges if there

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Think to a Cypher query like this:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE <complex condition>
RETURN n
```

But I need to return also possible edges between those nodes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE <complex condition>
WITH COLLECT(n) AS nodes
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)
WHERE (n IN nodes) AND (m in nodes)
AND id(n)>id(m)
RETURN n,r,m
```